# Symfony ORM PostRemove with soft deletable

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, soft-delete

I have an entity `category` and another entity `article` joined with `cat_id` and cascaded remove.

The `category` entity is [softDeleteable](http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/softdeleteable.html)

When i try to delete a `category`, the default behaviour is to delete related articles because they are cascaded onDelete.

I want to detect the doctrine orm event `PostRemove` in the entity `article` if i soft deleted the parent category of the article.

The doctrine can't detect `PostRemove` ORM event in the `article` entity and only detect `PreRemove` event.

When i disable softDeleteable extension it works fine, but i want to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen to the following events:

- [preSoftDelete](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/lib/Gedmo/SoftDeleteable/SoftDeleteableListener.php#L71)
- [postSoftDelete](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/lib/Gedmo/SoftDeleteable/SoftDeleteableListener.php#L88)

on the `Category` entity.

Hope this help

Comment: But this cannot be used out of the box like `@ORM/PreRemove` in the entity it seems. You'd need to create annotations, a driver, override SoftDeletableListener.